# How to generate an AND with a grouped OR query, with LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling to understand how to come up with a query like the following, using LINQ ...

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE a = false AND (b = true OR c = true)
```

I'm using Entity Framework and LINQ to query my database. I've got a table and entity class that has some boolean columns, and looks like so ...

```
public class Foo
{
  public bool A { get; set; }
  public bool B { get; set; }
  public bool C { get; set; }
}

var foos = DbSet<Foo>();
```

I'm trying to write a query that will select these records in such a way that if I want to include columns that are true, they need to be OR'd together, not AND'd. For the properties that are not true, though, they need to exist as ANDs.

I'm sure this is something very basic but I'm just failing to see the simple solution. Specifically, I cannot figure out how to progressively add the OR clauses.

Edit:

To clarify my logic, I'll explain what I'm trying to make happen. I'm trying to write a filter query that would allow me to ask the database, "show me all Foos where either A is true, or B is true and C is not true". Or maybe the query would need to ask, "show me all Foos where C is true and A and B are not true".

This is a query to be used as part of an ASP.NET action method, filtering based on some check boxes. So, the action method knows whether A, B or C need to be filtered as true or false, I just need to write a LINQ expression that builds this query.

Comment: Just gave you an answer that I think will help with your more complex case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with buffjape. In your case I would progressively add Where clauses. I would do something like the following:

```
//start with the full set
var results = DbSet<Foo>();

//then build the where clause using conditional logic based on which checkboxes are checked

if(aCheckBoxIsChecked)
{
    results = results.Where(foo => foo.A == true); //each where you add is effectively an and
}

if(bCheckBoxIsChecked)
{
    results = results.Where(foo => foo.B == true);
}

... //and keep on with as many checkboxes as you have


if(aCheckBoxIsChecked && cCheckBoxIsChecked)
{
    results = results.Where(foo => foo.B != true);
}
else if(!aCheckBoxIsChecked)
{
    results = results.Where(foo => foo.B == true || foo.C == true);
}
else if(...) //any other clauses
{
    ... //any other logic
}

... //any other tests

/* The key insight, is that Linq will not execute your query until 
you try to access the results. Therefore, you can continue to build
an arbitrarily complex query until you've finished it, and then you
can execute it, as in the below line. */

return results.ToList(); //Execute. Or whatever method you want to use to execute the query.
```

So by incrementally building our your clauses you have complete flexibility to build arbitrary Linq Where clauses.

Like I said, I disagree with the assertion that progressively building your where clause is bad. Yes, you have to be careful, but it is a technique that gives you great flexibility when your where clause is driven by many different parameters.

Comment: Yes it can be useful. The problem is that result = result.Where(...); has an implicit AND, which programmers sometimes forget, and implementing OR becomes difficult. After fixing a few of those bugs, i now try and avoid multiple where clauses.

Comment: It is true. If you're not careful, you can introduce accidental bugs. You definitely should only use it in cases like this, where the logic is simply too complex to build in a single compact Where clause or where there are too many possible permutations to hard code.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ for this is almost identical to the SQL:

```
foos.Where(n => n.A == false && (n.B == true || n.C == true))
```

Comment: I think my confusion is how to deal with the "dynamic"ness of the properties being true or false. If `A` is true, it needs to become part of that `OR` expression, otherwise it needs to be part of the `AND` expression.

Comment: Ok, but if A is true, isn't the OR going to be true by definition if you're including A in the OR clause? Can you clarify your logic in the question, please.

Comment: Is it possible to show the exact logic you're trying to implement? Then we can show you the exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = foos.Where(x => !x.A && (x.B || a.C)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> If A is true, it needs to become part of that OR expression, otherwise
>   it needs to be part of the AND expression

You can use an [?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.100).aspx) operator.

```
var result = foos.Where (x => x.A ? x.B && x.C : x.B || x.C);
```

So if `x.A == true` statement will be `x.B && x.C`, or `x.B || x.C` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Trying to progressively add WHERE clauses is a classic Linq mistake:

```
  var results = foos.Where(n => n.A == false)
                    .Where(n => n.B == true);

  // Bug: testing C == true, but this ignores A
  results = results.Union(foos.Where(n => n.C == true));
```

Instead, always use one where clause:

```
  results = foos.Where(n => n.A == false && (n.B == true || n.C == true));
```

If the expression gets too large for one line, switch to query syntax:

```
  results = (from n in foos
             where (n.A == false)
                && (n.B == true || n.C == true)
             select n
            );
```

As a last resort, if the Where clause gets unreasonably long, use a sql stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE a = false AND (b = true OR c = true)
```

would be

```
foos.Where(x=>!x.a && (x.b || x.c));
```

alternatively you could do this as well:

```
foos
  .Where(x=>!x.a)
  .Where(x=>x.b || x.c);
```